# How to check if the ID exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

I am working with 3 tables in which the administrator enters the records for:

1. Student information
2. Course information
3. Assigning course to students

Now when I want to assign the course to a student I want to check two things.

- Student Id exists
- Course Id exists

Then after these check the assignment of courses would get complete.

For some reason I can not think of any logic so that's why I am here asking this question.

```
protected void btnAssignStudents_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
   StudentCourse assigncourse = new StudentCourse();
   assigncourse.Course_Id = txtCourse_Id.Text;
   assigncourse.Student_ID = txtStudentID.Text;
   db.StudentCourses.InsertOnSubmit(assigncourse);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Before submitting the changes I want to apply these checks.

[image]

What i exactly want is to check on assigning the course is that

- The course exists or not, If not return some message.
- If student ID exists, If not return some message.

If both exist then complete the assignment.

Comment: What the datatype used to those id's? if you used int,please check my answer .

Comment: Do you want to check if assignment already exist of if both student and course with specified id's exist?

Comment: is that three tables have any relations?

Comment: Question is not clear what exactly it want.

Comment: let me upload the schema for you.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar check now.

Comment: Still you didn't explain what you want to achieve. Do you want to check if ID's are existing or if this assignment already exists?

Comment: @TalalUrfQari What you want? do you want check if those id's ate already exists in student core table? or what?

Comment: I want to check if the Id's exist @Peri

Comment: So that is what my code does. Finish it already :)

Comment: @TalalUrfQari . Okay you want to check which table? You want to check core and student table? or studentcore table? or both table?

Comment: @RameshRajendran of course for student_Id i have to check the Student table and similarly for course_ID i need to check the course table.

Comment: @RameshRajendran the assignment is in the third table the student course table after checking the ID's

Comment: Ok, Now you can try my edited answer. Check for syntax.

Comment: @TalalUrfQari: My code does what you wan't. I answered it more then 1 hour ago!

Comment: @Peri i got negative points so i am just making it more clear. I am a newbie.

Comment: Ok, but why you don't upvote, mark as answer. Didn't we already answer your question - more than hour ago?

Comment: You have to mark answer on one of suggested answer. Comment on it if not work of you. You can also upvote question if it help to solve you problem.

Comment: @Peri yes it is working now!

Comment: So upvote not downvote!

Comment: @Peri i did, some one else downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void btnAssignStudents_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new StudentDataContext();

    // check whether both course and student with specified ID's exist
    // I let you make sure txtCourse_Id.Text and txtStudentID.Text is not null or empty
    if (db.Courses.Any(c => c.Course_Id == txtCourse_Id.Text 
        && db.Students.Any(s => s.Student_Id == txtStudentID.Text)
    {
        var assigncourse = new StudentCourse();
        assigncourse.Course_Id = txtCourse_Id.Text;
        assigncourse.Student_ID = txtStudentID.Text;
        db.StudentCourses.InsertOnSubmit(assigncourse);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really you know there exist `db.Students` and `c.Id` ?

Comment: He didn't show his all code. So I guessed.

Comment: Question clear mention what exactly he want: Object `StudentCourse` has `Course_Id` and `Student_ID`, SO question required check for same.

Comment: I think Id is not a string(because any one does not assign the values in string, It's should int value), and we can use ORM concept for this task

Comment: @RameshRajendran What ORM concept? This is code that OP provided so why you downvote?

Comment: The OP does not mention anything. So why you answered? Your answer is assumption for OP question same as my assumption for he can use ORM concept here .

Comment: and may be `c.Id == txtCourse_Id.Text` given conversion error if OP have used Int data type for those id's

Comment: I asked what ORM concept you mean?

Comment: Actually we have not any fault, the fault have OP Question. Have you any sense for check the condition for what table?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `Course_Id` and `Student_ID` are `varchar` or `nvarchar` in db:

```
protected void btnAssignStudents_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
    StudentCourse assigncourse = new StudentCourse();
    var course = db.Course.Where(cr=>cr.Course_Id == txtCourse_Id.Text).ToList();
    var student = db.Student.Where(st=>st.Student_ID == txtStudentID.Text).ToList();
    if(course != null && course.Length > 0 && student != null && student.Length > 0)
    {
        assigncourse.Course_Id = txtCourse_Id.Text;
        assigncourse.Student_ID = txtStudentID.Text;
        db.StudentCourses.InsertOnSubmit(assigncourse);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

**Update:**

I am not sure what your requirement. but i guess one thing

you need to check  the id's if student and core table have exist and those id's haven't  exist in student core table before save.

If i am correct. you need to merge my and @peri answers

```
 protected void btnAssignStudents_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int CourseId=Convert.ToInt32(txtCourse_Id.Text);
        int StudentID=Convert.ToInt32(txtStudentID.Text);

        StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
        StudentCourse assigncourse = new StudentCourse();
        var _studentcourse = db.StudentCourse.Where(sc=>sc.Course_Id == CourseId && sc.Student_ID == StudentID).FirstOrDefault();          
        if(_studentcourse  != null && (db.Courses.Any(c => c.Course_Id == CourseId
        && db.Students.Any(s => s.Student_Id ==StudentID) )
        {
            assigncourse.Course_Id =CourseId;
            assigncourse.Student_ID = StudentID;
            db.StudentCourses.InsertOnSubmit(assigncourse);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

else you need to check if those id's not exist in Student core table only befor save

You need this code

```
 protected void btnAssignStudents_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int CourseId=Convert.ToInt32(txtCourse_Id.Text);
            int StudentID=Convert.ToInt32(txtStudentID.Text);

            StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
            StudentCourse assigncourse = new StudentCourse();
            var _studentcourse = db.StudentCourse.Where(sc=>sc.Course_Id == CourseId && sc.Student_ID == StudentID).FirstOrDefault();          
            if(_studentcourse  != null )
            {
                assigncourse.Course_Id =CourseId;
                assigncourse.Student_ID = StudentID;
                db.StudentCourses.InsertOnSubmit(assigncourse);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```